# How to use a single layout for multiple controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a layout for posts. The postscontroller redirects to this layout . I want my blog controller to use the same layout . I do not to put the layout as my application.html.erb since all other pages uses a different layout and I have put that as my applicationlayout.

Can i do something like this in my blog controller?
    render :layout => "post"

If so which view page my yield command retrieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, `render :layout => 'post'` will do it. The `yield` in the layout will yield as you would expect a `yield` in the application layout to.

To set a controller-wide layout, use `layout 'layout_name'` at the top of your controller.